# Variable column name in SQL lite and Python

Tags: python, sqlite

my question is, as the title says, how I can create a variable column in SQL lite used in Pyhton.

Here's my code, to show you what exactly I mean:

```
#Table with variables
def dynamic_data_entry(list_name, num, column):
    element_name = list_name[num]
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO myliltable (column) VALUES (?)", element_name)
    con.commit()
```

I want to insert the column name, when I call the function, so I can use the function for more than one column, but I keep getting an error, that the column 'column' doesn't exist.
Is there another way to do this, so I can change set the column name when I call the function, or just change the SQL part.

If there is a thread about this already, I would appreciate it, if you could link it, so I can read it myself (I couldn't find anything similar to this topic yet, which worked).

Thanks in advance, I appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the string's `format()` method to *insert* the column name into the SQL string:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO myliltable ({}) VALUES (?)".format(column),
            element_name)
```

You can find more information in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Comment: Would this introduce any type of security flaw as the official python sqlite3 documentation says not to use string methods in sql statements. Although, as long as this is not a variable accessible to the end user, it might not have the same type of security implications. Is my understanding correct?